# Checkbox click then remove validation using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**Problem :** When i checked in 'I am Fresher' Checkbox then i want to hide 'Experience field ' but Still his validation **Not hide / Remove** so my form not being submitting.

**I Need :**
When i checked 'I am fresher' then hide only Experience field and his validation.

```
     $('.fresher_checked').click(function(){
       if (this.checked) {
           $('div.imfresher').hide();
       } else {
           $('div.imfresher').show();
       }
   });
```

Detail Code in [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ravi142/grd9erjq/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if checkbox is checked in submit code too

```
 if($('.fresher_checked').is(":checked"))
      {

      return isNotEmpty($form.find('#f_name'), "Please enter your name.",
               $form.find('#elmNameError'))

               ;
      }
      else{

      return isNotEmpty($form.find('#f_name'), "Please enter your name.",
               $form.find('#elmNameError'))
               && isNotEmpty($form.find('#w_company_one'), "Please enter Experience.",
               $form.find('#elmExpError'))
               ;
      }
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ravi142/grd9erjq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this two rule in your JS. Before hide the field made it `disabled`.

```
$("#filedId").prop('disabled', true);
```

Don't check `disabled` fields in validation rule.

```
var isDisabled = $('textbox').prop('disabled');
```

`isDisabled` is a Boolean value

Answer (score 0):

**Please try This**

```
$( function() {
   // Set initial focus

     $('.fresher_checked').click(function(){
       if (this.checked) {
            $("#w_company_one").prop('disabled', true); 
           $('div.imfresher').hide();
       } else {
           $("#w_company_one").prop('disabled', false); 
           $('div.imfresher').show();
       }
   });

   //validation
    $('#signup_form').on('submit', function() {
      var $form = $(this);
      // return false would prevent default submission
      return isNotEmpty($form.find('#f_name'), "Please enter your name.",
               $form.find('#elmNameError'))
               && isNotEmpty($form.find('#w_company_one'), "Please enter Experience.",
               $form.find('#elmExpError'))
               ;
   });

   });

 function isNotEmpty(inputElm, errMsg, errElm) {
   var isValid = (inputElm.val().trim() !== "");
   if(inputElm.is(':disabled')){
    return true;
   }
   else
   {
    postValidate(isValid, errMsg, errElm, inputElm);
    return isValid;
   } 
}

function postValidate(isValid, errMsg, errElm, inputElm) {
   if (!isValid) {
      // Show errMsg on errElm, if provided.
      if (errElm !== undefined && errElm !== null
            && errMsg !== undefined && errMsg !== null) {
         errElm.html(errMsg);
      }
      // Set focus on Input Element for correcting error, if provided.
      if (inputElm !== undefined && inputElm !== null) {
         inputElm.addClass("errorBox");  // Add class for styling
         inputElm.focus();
      }
   } else {
      // Clear previous error message on errElm, if provided.
      if (errElm !== undefined && errElm !== null) {
         errElm.html('');
      }
      if (inputElm !== undefined && inputElm !== null) {
         inputElm.removeClass("errorBox");
      }
   }
}
```